# How to select from mysql db php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Are these 2 equivalent, if not how can I make them. I'm using php/Mysql (I'll use mysqli later)

```
mysql_select_db("db_App", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM AppOne");
```

OR

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db_App.AppOne"); // how can I get this to work like above?
```

Comment: I really wouldn't use the mysql_* functions if I were you, they're not being maintained anymore, are intended for old versions of MySQL and are deprecated in all but name.  You should switch to a more modern database layer such as mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 2):

You'll always have to select a database. From then on, specifying the database in the query is useless. It's better not to specify it there anyway, as that'd make you run into troubles if your database changes at some point.

Comment: Well then how do I use join, that requires 2 different databases?

Comment: no, it works fine whitout selecting a database, as long as you specify the databse in each query

Comment: Joining is usually done on tables in the same database, so specifying is redundant. If you're trying to join tables in multiple databases, reconsider your database model.

Answer (score 1):

if you skip the `$link` in `mysql_select_db("db_App", $link);`
they should do the same.